# Не изменяется разрешение изображения

Tags: python, изображения, opencv

На вход дается картинка с разрешением 2560x1440 так:

```
image = cv2.VideoCapture('image.jpg')
image.set(3, 640)
image.set(4, 480)
print(image.get(3),'x',image.get(4))
```

но метод `set` разрешение картинки не меняет.

Какое может быть ещё решение?

Comment: из вопроса непонятно - вы читаете картинку или видеопоток?

Comment: @MaxU поправил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете функцию `cv2.VideoCapture()` - она предназначена для чтения видеопотока.

Если вам нужно прочитать и изменть разрешение одного изображения - это можно сделать так:

```
# читаем исходную картинку
In [79]: img = cv2.imread(r'D:\download\lena.jpg')
# разрешение
In [80]: img.shape
Out[80]: (512, 512, 3)
# меняем разрешение и сохраняем в переменную `new`
In [81]: new = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
# разрешение после изменения разрешения
In [82]: new.shape
Out[82]: (100, 100, 3)
```

---

Чтобы прочитать изображение по интернет-ссылке:

```
url = 'http://...'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret,img = cap.read()
```

Comment: а что если картинка берётся из ссылки? я ранее спрашивал как открыть такую картинку,и мне ответили про помощи cv2.VideoCapture()